# How to put separator line on UITableView to specific section?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I've a `UITableView` with some sections. I want that just one section had separator lines for rows.

I tried this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 1, 0, 0) // With other values too.
    }
    ...
    return cell
}
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: try cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero for all the sections you dont want the separator for so basically if indexPath.section != 1 {
     cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}

Comment: add a custom view of height 1 with width equal to cell width. show in section 1 and hide in else .... also don't forget to hide default separator  of tableView.

Comment: none works......

Comment: @Augusto - Add ***4 extra spaces*** at the beginning of a line to indent the length of a tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extension to UITableViewCell:

```
extension UITableViewCell {

  func hideSeparator() {
    self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: self.bounds.size.width, bottom: 0, right: 0)
  }

  func showSeparator() {
    self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
  }
}
```

So you can use it in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

```
if indexPath.section == 1 { 
    cell.hideSeparator()
} else {
    cell.showSeparator()
}
```

Comment: Your code not works to me, but your information was usefully to solve my problem.

Comment: You know say to me why line not use all width space? The line leave a little blank space of left side.

Comment: @Augusto it's default inset for UITableView in iOS. To remove left space set : tableView.separatorInset = .zero

Comment: This works, but the `x` offset of Title HeaderView is seted to 0.

Comment: There is no another methods to do it, so you should arrange your header view offsets by code as you need in this case.